# Data truncation: Incorrect DATETIME value '' when using a CREATE TABLE SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, casting, mariadb, sql-insert

I am attempting to create a table on MariaDB 10.3 from a SELECT statement. The table contains the customer information and a column showing the missing elements for that customer row. Here is the example setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `customerTest` (
  `custid` int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `firstname` char(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` char(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `customerTest` VALUES (1,'Fred',NULL,'1950-01-01'),(2,'Barney',NULL,NULL),(3,'Wilma','Flintstone',NULL);
```

The query works when not being used in a CREATE TABLE statement.

```
SELECT custid, customerMissingDemographics FROM (
    SELECT custid, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',',FName,LName,Birthdate)) AS customerMissingDemographics FROM (
            SELECT c.custid,
            CASE WHEN firstname = '' OR firstname IS NULL THEN 'First Name' ELSE NULL END AS FName,
            CASE WHEN lastname = '' OR lastname IS NULL THEN 'Last Name' ELSE NULL END LName,
            CASE WHEN birthdate = '' OR birthdate IS NULL THEN 'Birthdate' ELSE NULL END Birthdate
            FROM `customerTest` c
            GROUP BY custid
            ) computeMissingDemographics
    GROUP BY computeMissingDemographics.custid
    ) aggregateMissingDemographics
 WHERE customerMissingDemographics <> ''
```

The query returns:

```
custid|customerMissingDemographics
------|---------------------------
     1|Last Name                  
     2|Last Name,Birthdate        
     3|Birthdate
```

However, if I attempt to use `CREATE TABLE test` to create a table with the results from this query, it fails with 
`SQL Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: ''`

I have attempted to CAST the fields in the computeMissingDemographics table to no effect. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting; it seems some implicit casting in the `SELECT` query is disabled when it it used in a `CREATE TABLE` query. Your issue is in this test:

```
birthdate = ''
```

as `''` is not a valid `DATE` value. You can resolve the issue by explicitly casting `birthdate` to `CHAR` before comparison i.e.

```
CAST(birthdate AS CHAR) = ''
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c5a920165ea58e90501d36142c5dc73f)

Answer (score 1):

The expression for `Birthdate` in the `SELECT` failed to be defined the way you wanted.

When using

```
CREATE TABLE t
    SELECT ...
```

You can optionally add/change columns/indexes.  In your case, I suggest

```
CREATE TABLE t (
       `Birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL
               )
    SELECT ...
```